# Не могу поменять значение data.center

Tags: vue.js, google-maps, vuex

я Добавил маркер, но мне нужно подставить 
свои координаты из бд. как поменять center и markers[0].position на свои this.order.coordinates.lat и lng

```
 export default {
    name: "order-view",
    data: () => ({
        order: {
            title: '',
            description: '',
            coordinates: '',
            address:'',
            date: '',
            time_period:'',
            budget_scale_id: '',
            user: {
                first_name: '',
                last_name: '',
            }
        },
        zoom: 2,
        center: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
        markers: [{
            position: {
                lat: 0,
                lng: 0,
            }
        }],
    }),
    async mounted() {
        let order = await this.$store.dispatch('orders/getOrder', {
            id: this.$route.params.id
        });
        this.order = order.order;
        this.order.user = order.user;
    },
}

        <gmap-map  class="form-control maps" :zoom="zoom"  :center="center">
                        <GmapMarker v-for="(marker, index) in markers"
                                    :key="index"
                                    :position="marker.position"
                                    :clickable="false"
                                    :draggable="false"
                        />
                    </gmap-map>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, было несоответствие типов, заработался, не вижу видимых ошибок. стоило всего лишь спарсить

```
async created() {
            let order = await this.$store.dispatch('orders/getOrder', {
                id: this.$route.params.id
            });
            this.order = order.order;
            this.order.user = order.user;
            this.markers[0].position.lat = parseFloat(this.order.coordinates.lat);
            this.markers[0].position.lng = parseFloat(this.order.coordinates.lng);
        },
```